# polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN_KEEP not working with fprintd

Tags: linux, arch-linux, polkit, fingerprint

I'm currently configuring [fprintd](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/) on my computer. It is a powerful tool that makes the fingerprint authorization possible on Unix-like systems. However, a user can add modify and delete fingerprints without password authorization simply with `fprintd-enroll`. That's a security vulnerability as anyone can register their own fingerprint to my device when they have physical access to my computer.

To overcome this vulnerability, I noticed that [polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) might help in enforcing password promation before the physical user modifying my fingerprint credential. After reading the polkit's manual, I end up with the following policy rule locating at `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/50-net.reactivated.fprint.device.enroll.rules`:

```
polkit.addRule(function (action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "net.reactivated.fprint.device.enroll") {
    return subject.user == "root" ? polkit.Result.YES : polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN_KEEP;
  }
})
```

I believe this rule can help force the admin users to provide the password, while allowing the root user to rescue the world, especially when something goes wrong. Also, as my current user is a member of the wheel group, it should be identified as a admin user according to `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/50-defaule.rules`:

```
/* -*- mode: js; js-indent-level: 4; indent-tabs-mode: nil -*- */

// DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, it will be overwritten on update
//
// Default rules for polkit
//
// See the polkit(8) man page for more information
// about configuring polkit.

polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {
    return ["unix-group:wheel"];
});
```

Everything looks fine until I was trying to test this setup by running `fprintd-enroll`:

```
[tjm@ArchPad ~]$ fprintd-enroll 
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
EnrollStart failed: Not Authorized: net.reactivated.fprint.device.enroll
[tjm@ArchPad ~]$
```

I'm kind of astonished that things were not working and an authorisation failure occurred. I tried change `polkit.Result.AUTH_ADMIN_KEEP` to `polkit.Result.AUTH_SELF_KEEP`, which unfortunately not helps. I hope there's going to be a way to fix this out.